# Firefox 108.0 jumps to different desktop

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, 22.10

I run Kmail (within Kontact) and Firefox in different Plasma virtual desktops under Kubuntu 22.10. When I click on a link in Kmail, I need to move to the Firefox desktop to see the result. This is fine, and what I want.

However, when I upgraded to the Firefox 108.0-2 snap installation today, what happens now is that when I click on a link in Kmail, the Firefox window jumps to the Kmail desktop.

Is this a bug, or WAD? How can I stop the behaviour? I don't see anything relevant under Plasma Configure Special Window Settings or Configure Special Application Settings for Firefox or Kontact.

Edit: The Firefox window also jumps to a different desktop if I open a link from Konsole or Libreoffice Calc, so this problem isn't related to Kmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more details in the thread at:
**Prevent a browser window from changing virtual desktops when an application on another desktop opens a link?**
https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/zm6gag/prevent_a_browser_window_from_changing_virtual/
which points to:
**Windows do not stay on the virtual desktop they are on**
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=462996

Edit: The problem is due to a bug in KWin; fixed in version 5.27 (see above link to bugs.kde.org).

Comment: Please consider adding details from these links into this answer...

Comment: Unfortunately there are no clear answers yet. For instance, someone has suggested it might be a problem with Firefox rather than KDE.